Ubuntu 12.04 (Linaro 13.04) usb mouse/keyboard not detected on LXDE
USB root hub device seems to be initialized but does not power up any devices (keyboard, mouse). So I cant use LXDE desktop, because keyboard and mouse are not detected. Another linux distro install (mister fpga on the arrow sockit device) can use mouse/keyboard powered up on the same device directly. Also the keyboard and two mouses tried work perfectly on other computers. so its a linux/software issue. I have not tried later version of ubuntu, because it requires software setup present in the install linux image that is not present in normal install versions directly.
What would be the issue?
Note: I’m using the console through serial terminal, so I can make normal modifications on the console, using keyboard and mouse.
lsusb output:
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

udevadm monitor: shows nothing when connecting an usb device.
Some boot up log:
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
usbcore: registered new device driver usb
…
usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.13.0-00298-g3c7cbb9-dirty dwc2_hsotg
usb usb1: SerialNumber: ffb40000.usb
hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
…
usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
usbhid: USB HID core driver


Ubuntu 13.04: are you sure that is your version? You couldn't install much on that anyways, that version of Ubuntu has been unsupported for roughly a decade.

I have to use this version because of the board. its likely 12.04 quantal, but its named Linaro 13.04. Any comments about eol or unsupported dont matter here. only the trick to make it work, as itself. only the original sd-card install image matters. it contains the main software. also I changed /etc/apt/sources.list to point to old-releases.ubuntu.com, so updates work.

no comment intended, just needed the clarification whether you're really using that version; it's 2024, so 2023.04 is a relatively likely thing, so 2013.04 is a likely typo.

yes the 2013 board default install image is using 12.04 ubuntu quantal. also I was able to get the display to desktop by typing "startx" in the serial terminal, but still no mouse/keyboard turning on. please stay on the topic of getting the mouse and keyboard working. Linaro 13.04 is not a typo, that's what the distro boot up says.

I'm not trying to use 2024 version of ubuntu or anything related to the current year. I'm specifically trying to use the old 12.04 version. I hope this is clear now. any comments should be directed towards the 12.04 ubuntu version, no matter how unreasonable that would feel like.

yes, I understand that. What I was trying to say is that if someone walks into your bakery and asks for "yesteryear's bread", you assume they might have meant "yesterday's bread", so you ask to confirm.

very yesterdays bread. lol. I'm also 99% sure that there is no contact problems with the usb otg port cable. as the mister sockit worked fine on the same kb/mouse.
